# Map multiple tables to a single entity dynamically

Tags: entity-framework, orm, mapping

I have some tables which should add to my database every year and name of databases contains the year (like sell2005) and iv'e written some `ef` queries on these tables ,and queries can only be on a single entity (like sell2005) but what should i do when sell2006 or sell2007 add ? how can i manage them with that single query which iv'e written before?
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way. EF is simply not tool for this scenario. For EF you must have "single table" so you must either use partitioning with one real database table partitioned by year or you must build a view on top of these tables.

The problem is that in EF you have strict relation between classes and tables. You cannot have single class mapped to multiple tables even if they are exactly same (except inheritance which **is not solution for you**). So the workaround would require to have multiple SSDL/MSL mappings - one for each table and construct correct context instance with correct mapping for every query. As I know dynamic changes of mapping are not possible (except modifying SSDL/MSL files before using them).